# wifi or Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer

Tags: android, wifi

I want to work with Wifi connection via Android Devices (for example I want to send a command with my device to home router via Internet and my router send this command to a wifi module) when I refer to Developer Android APIs, I see a section that named "Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer". what differences exist between wifi (working android devices with access point like home router) and "Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer". Is "Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer" same wifi Direct ? why Google didnt discusses about simple wifi ? please help.

Answer (score 3):

1. WiFi P2P (Peer-to-Peer) and WiFi Direct are both the same thing.
2. There are two main differences between "normal" WiFi and WiFi P2P (from the developer's point of view):

   - A WiFi p2p connection (something you establish from code) is a direct connection between *two* devices. You can **understand** it as a sort of temporary (created for the time of the connection) "normal" WiFi network created for the purpose of communicating those *two* devices. A "normal" WiFi connection basically translates to a situation when a device is connected to a broadcasted (by some device - e.g. home access point, or a smartphone) WiFi network. This all basically means that to send data between two devices using WiFi P2P, those devices **DO NOT** have to be connected to the same WiFi network (as long as those devices know how to connect to each other using wifi p2p). Unfortunatelly good news with WiFi P2P end right here, because:
   - Designing a WiFi P2P connection based system is extremely difficult if you want to make it at least reasonably robust. This is mostly due to the lack of documentation on that subject (in Android Dev), and due to Android's WiFi p2p unpredictability (I know what I'm talking about - I was recently desigining such system).
3. You're wrong saying that Google didn't discuss "simple" WiFi. You just need to remember that connecting to "simple" WiFi is just not that complicated, so they didnt have to do a guide like they did for WiFi P2P. All information considering "normal" WiFi are there (at Android Developer), its just spread over many classes.

Tell me what you think is not discussed?

Also you should try to describe the exact thing your application needs to do (with WiFi), so I can maybe give you a hint whether you should try your luck with WiFi P2P or not.

Comment: As I said, I want to send commands from my Android device in a Other place (for example a place out of my city) via Internet to a WiFi module. In this situation, I think I have to utilize my home router as a Access Point to Receive my commands from Internet and then, my Router sends my commands to WiFi module. In this case should I use "WiFi P2P" or "simple WiFi" ? I think Google dosn't discuss because, I see only WiFi P2P section. I'm confused. please say is there the simple wifi Guide in that section? I mean does Google learn "simple WiFi" Classes in same section? thanks

Comment: You dont need a guide from Android Dev because the thing you wanna do and "a problem" you have with this is not android-related at all. It's an Internet-based (or network in general) question. The thing you call a "wifi module" would need to have a public Ip Address to which you could be sending things "for example from a place out of your city". WiFi direct is not for you for sure. Its used for lets say "close wireless communication". You need basic Internet-based networking.